# YAML translations for simple form 'select'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, simple-form

In a Rails app, in a form.html.haml, I've got a simple form input as:

`= f.input :free, as: :select, include_blank: false`

I want to translate the options in the select (which are currently 'yes' and 'no') but I'm really struggling to find the correct YAML to do it.

I found the documentation on translations selects on https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n :

---

*Simple Form also has support for translating options in collection helpers. For instance, given a User with a :gender attribute, you might want to create a select box showing translated labels that would post either male or female as value. With Simple Form you could create an input like this:*

`f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female]`

*And Simple Form will try a lookup like this in your locale file, to find the right labels to show:*

> en:
>    simple_form:
>      options:
>
> ```
>  user:
>    gender:
>      male: 'Male'
>      female: 'Female'
> ```

*You can also use the defaults key as you would do with labels, hints and placeholders.*

---

But I couldn't make it work myself, and I've tried every possibility I could think of!

Have I included enough information there, or do I need to add anything? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

*EDIT : sorry for the bad formatting on the simple_form example; I can't seem to make it format properly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a .yml file like

```
simple_form:
  options:
    defaults:
      gender:
        male: 'Male'
        female: 'Female'
```

and use them as

```
= f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female]
```

If you want to use yes and no in the file, you have to quote them, as they're reserved keywords:

```
'yes': 'yes'
'no': 'no'
```